# How to get corresponding data of option selected in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have dropdown for `UserRole` in my form. JSON data is:

```
{"userName":"John","UserRole":[{"roleId":"URR000001","roleName":"ReleaseManager"},{"roleId":"URR000002","roleName":"ROUsers"}]};
```

Using jQuery, how can I get `roleId` for its corresponding `roleName` selected?

Read question carefully. If any confusion, please comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (in `role` put role from dropdown which you are looking for e.g. "ROUsers" like in snippet below)

```js
let data = {"userName":"John","UserRole":[{"roleId":"URR000001","roleName":"ReleaseManager"},{"roleId":"URR000002","roleName":"ROUsers"}]};

let role="ROUsers"
let result = data.UserRole.find(x=> x.roleName==role );

console.log(result);
```

We use here array [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/find) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Might be useful to warn OP that you're writing in ES2015 :) some people might not be familiar with it yet.

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski Thank you so much. This answer was absolutely useful.